# Linkage error with glui32.lib and libcd.lib on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, linkage

I am trying to port a (very) old project of mine from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010.

The project is an OpenGL application, and as such, it uses the following libraries (amongst others):

- glu32.lib
- glui32.lib
- glut32.lib
- opengl32.lib

The `glui32.lib` library links the `libcd.lib` library, which is not supported on Visual Studio 2010.

So I need to find a version of the `glui32.lib` library, which links the `libcmtd.lib` library instead.

**My questions are:**

- Is there any such version of the `glui32.lib` library?
- If yes - where can I download it?
- If no - can I use the `libcd.lib` library on Visual Studio 2010?
- If yes - where can I download it?
- If no - is there any other way for me to solve this linkage error?

**UPDATE**

I'm leaving the answer below as the accepted one, but here is a workaround for porting an OpenGL project from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2010 (after creating the project in Visual Studio 2010):

- Right click the project and choose *Properties*.
- Open *Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor*.
- In the *Preprocessor Definitions* entry, add **GLUT_BUILDING_LIB**.
- In the *Runtime Library* entry, choose **Multi-threaded (/MT)** or **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**.
- Open *Configuration Properties --> Linker -->Input*.
- In the *Additional Dependencies* entry, add **glu32.lib;glui32.lib;glut32.lib;opengl32.lib**.
- In the *Ignore Specific Default Libraries* entry, add **libcd.lib**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rebuild [GLUI](http://glui.sourceforge.net/).  The MSVS project they ship converts without issue to VS2010.

You will have to point it at your GLUT build though.

Comment: Yes, I figured I could possibly download the source code and rebuild it (though I was hoping that there would be a way to avoid it). Anyway, what do you mean by "point it at your GLUT build"? Does it need to link `glut32.lib`?

Comment: Yes, it needs access to the GLUT headers/library.  If you use FreeGLUT you don't have to tell it specifically which `.lib` to use, just the directory there the `.lib` is ("`Additional Library Directories`").