# Glut Initialisation Function

Tags: c++, opengl

I just wanted to ask in particular about the function glutInit in OpenGL and Microsoft Visual Studio C++.

I was looking through the GLUT documentation and came across how it is declared using:

```
void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv);
```

I inserted this code in the main.cpp file at the top but got an error.

When I traced the error it led me to the following block of code.

```
/* GLUT initialization sub-API. */
GLUTAPI void APIENTRY glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv);
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK)
GLUTAPI void APIENTRY __glutInitWithExit(int *argcp, char **argv, void (__cdecl *exitfunc)(int));
#ifndef GLUT_BUILDING_LIB
static void APIENTRY glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK(int *argcp, char **argv) { __glutInitWithExit(argcp, argv, exit); }
#define glutInit glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK
#endif
#endif
```

Does the above code already declare the `glutInit` function and secondly can you use:

`void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv)` in `main.cpp`

to add other functions inside it such as the core glut functions.

Comment: I tried making void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv); work in visual studio but it complains of an error being incompatible. How would you successfully insert void glutInit(int *argcp, char **argv); in your main.cpp file then.

Comment: Have you added `GLUT_BUILDING_LIB` to your preprocessor definitions in the project settings?

Comment: no I haven't. How do you do that

Comment: See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21945354/1382251 (read the 'UPDATE' section). In addition, if you want, I can give you may GLUT and GLUI initialization sequence (but I would have to do it in an answer, which would not be 100% corresponding to this question).

Answer (score 1):

In order to add OpenGL libraries in a VS project:

1. Right click the project and choose *Properties*.
2. Open *Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Preprocessor*.
3. In the *Preprocessor Definitions* entry, add **GLUT_BUILDING_LIB**.
4. In the *Runtime Library* entry, choose **Multi-threaded (/MT)** or **Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)**.
5. Open *Configuration Properties --> Linker -->Input*.
6. In the *Additional Dependencies* entry, add **glu32.lib;glui32.lib;glut32.lib;opengl32.lib**.
7. In the *Ignore Specific Default Libraries* entry, add **libcd.lib**.

Please note that depending on your OpenGL version, you might be able to skip step 4 and step 7.

Also, although possibly not directly related to your question, here is "my favorite" initialization sequence:

```
void CreateSimulation();
void DestroySimulation();
void AdjustSimulation(int iWindowId);

void OnIdle();
void OnDisplay();
void OnReshape(int iWidth,int iHeight);
void OnSpecial(int iKey,int iX,int iY);
void OnKeyboard(unsigned char iKey,int iX,int iY);
void OnMouse(int iButton,int iState,int iX,int iY);

void main()
{
    int iWidth  = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);
    int iHeight = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(iWidth,iHeight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    int iWindowId = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE);

    CreateSimulation();
    atexit(DestroySimulation);
    AdjustSimulation(iWindowId);

    GLUI_Master.set_glutIdleFunc(OnIdle);
    GLUI_Master.set_glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
    GLUI_Master.set_glutReshapeFunc(OnReshape);
    GLUI_Master.set_glutSpecialFunc(OnSpecial);
    GLUI_Master.set_glutKeyboardFunc(OnKeyboard);
    GLUI_Master.set_glutMouseFunc(OnMouse);

    glutMainLoop();
}

void CreateSimulation()
{
    ...
}

void DestroySimulation()
{
    ...
}

void AdjustSimulation(int iWindowId)
{
    ...
}

void OnIdle()
{
    ...
}

void OnDisplay()
{
    ...
}

void OnReshape(int iWidth,int iHeight)
{
    ...
}

void OnSpecial(int iKey,int iX,int iY)
{
    switch (iKey)
    {
        ...
    }
}

void OnKeyboard(unsigned char iKey,int iX,int iY)
{
    switch (iKey)
    {
        ...
    }
}

void OnMouse(int iButton,int iState,int iX,int iY)
{
    switch (iButton)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```